# How to create a NLC in watson

Tags: nlp, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-dialog, nl-classifier

I am trying to create a classifier using Watson Natural language classifier(NLC) but the status of that classifier is set to **Training** but if I have to use it should be in **Available** state. How or when it will change to **Available** state.

Regards

Comment: Could you explain a little more? Or show a screenshot of the Watson NLC?

Comment: Hi @alvas it works as Simon suggested. Thanks for ur interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Training" state means that NLC has received content and is currently building. Depending on the amount of content you have sent in, it can take some time.

2000 questions can take an hour or so to build (based on ones I've worked on). But there is no fixed time for question sets.

Comment: Thanks @Simon O'Doherty.

Comment: Do u have any links to docs which have related data for NLC creation and usage.? @Simon O'Doherty

Comment: Main documentation is here: http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/nl-classifier/